# The expectation of the half-normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

For the density function below, I need to find $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$. For $E(X)$, I did the following steps and got the answer of $-2/\sqrt{2\pi}$. However, this is incorrect as the correct answer is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$. I am unsure what I did incorrectly. For $E(X^2)$, is there any easier way to do it than by integration by parts? Thanks for the help.

Also, I tried a different approach that didn't work at all and I was wondering why it was incorrect. I split it up into two standard  normals by adding them. Then, I used the theorem that the sum of two normals is also normal with a mean that is the sum of the two original normals and a variance that is a sum of the variances of the original normals. Going by that logic, I should get a normal with a mean of $0$ and a variance of $2$; however, that is obviously incorrect, so I am just wondering why.

$$ f(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx, \ \ \ \ \ 0 < x < \infty $$
$$
E(X) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx.
$$
Let $u = \frac{x^2}{2}$. 
$$
= - \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
$$

Comment: But it does not show how you arrived at the negative answer.

Comment: e^-u from 0 to infinite is -1

Comment: Thank you! I forgot the negative that preceded e^-u when integrating. Much appreciated.

Comment: This is the [half-normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution).  Note $2/\sqrt{2 \pi} = \sqrt{2/\pi}$.

Comment: How do I now go about finding E(X^2) without having to use integration by parts? Can I compare it to the standard normal and somehow infer E(X^2) from it?

Comment: BTW, this is actually about the expectation of the _absolute value_ of a normally distributed random variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you got a negative answer, my first suspicion is that you didn't deal carefully with the bounds of integration.  If $u=-x^2/2$, then as $x$ goes from $0$ to $\infty$, $u$ goes from $0$ to $-\infty$.  Since $du=-x\;dx$, the integral $\int_0^\infty$ becomres
$$\int_0^{-\infty} -e^u\;du.$$
So think about how to change that to $\int_{-\infty}^0\cdots\cdots$.

Also, it wouldn't hurt to recall a bit of algebra in order to understand the relationship between $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi\;{}}}$ and $\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$.

Answer (score 3):

For calculating $E[X^2]$, you need not do integration by parts.

HINT Suppose $Y$ is distributed according to the *standard* normal $N(0,1)$. Do you know how to calculate $E[Y^2]$ (given its mean and variance)?

Secondly, the random variables $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are identically distributed. Can you see why? How would this fact help us?

Comment: Are they identically distributed because X^2 is an even function?

Comment: @Srivatsan, I temporarily submitted a comment to the question, explaining basically your point here. Sorry about that, it seems that I somehow missed your answer. Comment now deleted.

Comment: No problem @Didier. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no way you can obtain a negative answer, since $x>0$ and $f(x)$ is always positive, since it is a pdf. Integration has to go along the following lines:

$\varphi(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty}x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}d(\frac{x^2}{2}) =\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}dt=-[e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}] \vert^{\infty}_{0}=1$

Comment: I don't understand the notation on the left-hand side. What is $\varphi(x)$ supposed to denote and why is it a function of $x$?

Comment: it's the integral in OP's question

Comment: sigma, please read carefully @cardinal comment, you cannot have some $x$ in $\varphi$ and in the integral (besides, you did not define $\varphi$).

Comment: from OP, $EX=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \varphi(x)$

Comment: Sorry, but your last comment does not make sense either. $\mathbb E X$ is a *number*, not a function of $x$, and $\varphi$ is not found anywhere in the question, as far as I can tell. :)